# Does MMA have a maximum likelihood estimation function?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I want to use MMA to solve question 23 in [this post](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/e1123d554a73f242336c1eb91a37f111f1850dbd.html):

[image]

[image]

**The English translation of this question is as follows:**

Let the probability density function of population $X$ be $f\left(x, \sigma^{2}\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\mathrm{A}}{\sigma} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}} & x \geq \mu \\
0 & x<\mu
\end{array}\right.$, where $\mu$ is a known parameter, $\sigma$ is an unknown parameter, and $\sigma>0$, $A$ is constant $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ (I've got the value of $A$ in advance). $X1$, $X2$,...,$Xn$ are simple random samples from $X$.

**How to use the built-in probability theory function of MMA to calculate the maximum likelihood estimator of $\sigma^2$.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done with `EstimatedDistribution` and the `ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"` option:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100];
EstimatedDistribution[data, NormalDistribution[0, σ], 
  ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"
]
```

> NormalDistribution[0, 0.918944]

Use `ProbabilityDistribution` if you need to define a distribution from a custom probability density function.

Answer (score 1):

The density you have is related to a half Normal distribution but that is not essential to know to obtain the maximum likelihood estimates and obtain an estimate of precision for that estimator.

First create a distribution based on the density:

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[(Sqrt[(2/π)]/σ) Exp[-(x - μ)^2/(2 σ^2)], {x, μ, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> σ > 0]
```

Take a random sample from that distribution.

```
SeedRandom[12345];
data = RandomVariate[dist /. {μ -> 4, σ -> 3}, 1000];
```

Now find the maximum likelihood estimate of $\sigma$ (as you say that $\mu$ is known.

```
mle = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist /. μ -> 4]
(* {σ -> 2.93267} *)
```

To get an estimate of the standard error of the estimator perform the following:

```
logL = LogLikelihood[dist /. μ -> 4, data];
stdErr = Sqrt[-1/(D[logL, {σ, 2}]) /. mle]
(* 0.0655764 *)
```

If you did recognize that the distribution was related to a half normal distribution (with $X-\mu$ having a half normal distribution with parameter $\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{\sigma }$), then you could use the following:

```
FindDistributionParameters[data - μ /. μ -> 4, HalfNormalDistribution[Sqrt[π/2]/σ]]
(* {σ -> 2.93267} *)
```

You'd still need to use the `LogLikelihood` function to obtain an estimate of the standard error.